# Issues with joining many tables getting to many values

Tags: sql, join

This is my script:

```
select c.rendering_id as prov_number, c.begin_date_of_service as date_of_service, 
    c.practice_id as group_number, v.enc_nbr as invoice, p.person_nbr as patient, 
    v.enc_nbr as invoice_number, c.charge_id as transaction_number, 
    t.med_rec_nbr as primary_mrn, p.last_name, p.first_name, 
    z.payer_id as orig_fsc_number, z.payer_id as curr_fsc_number, 
    c.location_id as location_number, c.closing_date as posting_date, 
    c.quantity as service_units, c.amt as charge_amount, 
    c.cpt4_code_id as procedure_code, r.description as procedure_name, 
    x.tran_code_id as pay_code_number, ISNULL([modifier_1],'') as modifier_code_1, 
    ISNULL([modifier_2],'') as modifier_code_2, ISNULL([modifier_3],'') as modifier_code_3, 
    ISNULL ([icd9cm_code_id],'') as dx_code_1, ISNULL ([icd9cm_code_id_2],'') as dx_code_2, 
    ISNULL ([icd9cm_code_id_3],'') as dx_code_3, ISNULL ([icd9cm_code_id_4],'') as dx_code_4

from charges c, person p, patient t, patient_encounter v, encounter_payer z, cpt4_code_mstr r, transactions x

where c.person_id = p.person_id
  and c.person_id = t.person_id
  and c.person_id = v.person_id
  and c.person_id = z.person_id
  and c.cpt4_code_id = r.cpt4_code_id
  and c.person_id = x.person_id
  and c.practice_id = '0001'
  and c.closing_date >= GetDate() - 7
```

I should be getting about 14k rows but with this I am getting a couple hundred thousand. I feel like there should be an inner join here to correct it but I have read through a bunch of posts and can seem to get it working. Its by far the biggest pull I have ever done in SQL.

Any help would be greatly help.

Comment: Actually, you are already using inner joins in the above query.

Comment: Left joins could only give him *more* result rows.

Comment: You need to identify which tables have many to one relationships and add further conditions to filter the data down.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you Shane. Do you have some type of example? Sorry im a visual learner...lol

Comment: Well: if you get too many result rows, you have missed a keyfield that should have been matched. My guess is that there is a date or sequence-number somewhere in the v table, or that the patient<-->person relation is not a 1:1 match, or that there  are multiple transactions x per person, or ...

Comment: Simply put: what unnecessary repetitions do you see in your current results? ( btw, inner-joinified your query: http://pastebin.com/0cM5xugr )

Comment: exactly. but, remember: he is a visual learner.

Comment: Hmm now that I am looking there are more than one charges, encounters, and transactions per person in the 7 day time frame. How would I limit them?

Comment: Stop using implicit joins, they are are very ppor programming practice. THey are part of why you don't understand correctly what a join does.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the data structures and foreign key relationships, this answer is just educated speculation.  Before answering, though, you need to learn proper JOIN syntax.  Your query should look like:

```
 from charges c join
      person p
      on . . . .
```

That said, you problem is probably that you are joining along multiple dimensions at the same time.  Although not explicitly clear, I am guessing that a person could have multiple patient encounters, say A, B, and C.  A person might also have multiple charges, say 10, 11, and 12.

Your query will produce nine rows in this case, one for each combination.

In other words, you need to identify:

1. Verify the join keys between tables.  Is a table called transactions really joined to encounters and costs using the person_id?
2. Find out where you are getting cross products, and split into two subqueries that are then appropriately joined together.

I would suggest that you start with the first two tables, and see whether you get the expected row count for:

```
select *
from charges c join
     person p
     on c.person_id = p.person_id
where c.practice_id = '0001' and
     c.closing_date >= GetDate() - 7
```

Then build up the query one table at a time to get the results you want.

One last note, when using table aliases, I find it much clearer to use aliases that evoke the table.  "C" for charges is very good.  Consider something like "pe" for patient_encounters, and so on.

Comment: Yes I did try the path of the first two tables and that worked fine with inner join for the frist two then when I added table patient_encounter v is when i get to many rows. The patient_encounter does contain a person_id but I get 380k rows. I know there is more than one patient_encounter in the 7 day period but is there any way to clean up the results? Sorry if im not explaining correctly, as you can most likely tell SQL is not my best subject.

Comment: If you want to join on person id, then you need a subquery on patient enounters, where you group by person id in the subquery.  In other words, you need to figure out how to group the data at the person id level, in order to avoid duplication.

Comment: If you have a one to many relationship and you use a join you will get multiple records returned. That is normal and expected join behavior. If you only want one record per person then you have to do something to tell it which of the many records you want or you have to use some sort of function or forXML path to put in a comma delimited list in the column you want from that table.  Your problem right now is that you have no idea what record you want. Once you tell use that, we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this or you can use left join

```
select c.rendering_id as prov_number, c.begin_date_of_service as date_of_service, 
c.practice_id as group_number, v.enc_nbr as invoice, p.person_nbr as patient, 
v.enc_nbr as invoice_number, c.charge_id as transaction_number, 
t.med_rec_nbr as primary_mrn, p.last_name, p.first_name, 
z.payer_id as orig_fsc_number, z.payer_id as curr_fsc_number, 
c.location_id as location_number, c.closing_date as posting_date, 
c.quantity as service_units, c.amt as charge_amount, 
c.cpt4_code_id as procedure_code, r.description as procedure_name, 
x.tran_code_id as pay_code_number, ISNULL([modifier_1],'') as modifier_code_1, 
ISNULL([modifier_2],'') as modifier_code_2, ISNULL([modifier_3],'') as modifier_code_3, 
ISNULL ([icd9cm_code_id],'') as dx_code_1, ISNULL ([icd9cm_code_id_2],'') as dx_code_2, 
ISNULL ([icd9cm_code_id_3],'') as dx_code_3, ISNULL ([icd9cm_code_id_4],'') as dx_code_4

from charges c
inner join person p on c.person_id = p.person_id
inner join patient t on c.person_id = t.person_id
inner join patient_encounter v on c.person_id = v.person_id
inner join encounter_payer z on c.person_id = z.person_id
inner join cpt4_code_mstr r on c.cpt4_code_id = r.cpt4_code_id
inner join transactions x on c.person_id = x.person_id

where c.practice_id = '0001'
and c.closing_date >= GetDate() - 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you comment one inner join at a time and execute below query and see which of these joins is causing one to many relationship...when the count gives you say around 14 K that means the commented table is causing 1 to many relationship.

Otherwise best way is to find the relationship based on unique key,primary key and FK on these tables.

```
select 
count(c.person_id)
from charges c 
inner join person p on c.person_id = p.person_id 
inner join patient t on c.person_id = t.person_id 
inner join patient_encounter v on c.person_id = v.person_id 
inner join encounter_payer z on c.person_id = z.person_id 
inner join cpt4_code_mstr r on c.cpt4_code_id = r.cpt4_code_id 
inner join transactions x on c.person_id = x.person_id 

where c.practice_id = '0001' 
and c.closing_date >= GetDate() - 7
```

You can try

```
 select count(*) from <tablename> group by person_id having count(*) > 1
```

and repeat above query for all tables this will give you an idea on what kind of relationship between charges table and other tables. Offcourse use  cpt4_code_id for cpt4_code_mstr table but by name it looks like that this table is master table so it will have  a signle vale for each cpt4-code_id value in charges table.

I hope it will help

Comment: ok so I did that and found my trouble makers inner join patient_encounter v on c.person_id = v.person_id inner join encounter_payer z on c.person_id = z.person_id inner join transactions x on c.person_id = x.person_id

Comment: so i have to figure out how to slim them down to the 14k records that should show up from the charge table. Hmm so using something other than person_id as the link could help? I checked the patient_encounter table and that has a few columns that are the same as charges such as location_id but again that would be more than a 1 to 1 and practice_id but same issue.

Comment: That you need to find what kind of relationship exists between these two tables.Maybe talk to people who knows these table better or look some other queries in your database between these two tables.These must give you idea to add extra condition.I hope it will help.

Comment: Hmm there is a distinct value on the charge table of charge_id could I limit my orginal script to pull with a paramater of charge_id being distinct? I feel like that might clean things up...or am I way off base?